# How to draw graphics in intellij IDEA plugin ToolWindow?

Tags: java, swing, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Currently I'm about to developing custom gradle-based intellij IDEA plugin providing ToolWindow which draws graph about several software metrics.

With Swing GUI Designer, I can easily design layouts and design of UI, and mount to main toolwindow.

But how can I draw graphics like rectangles or circles using Graphics2D in ToolWindow?

I've tried to add non-palette component in GUI Designer, which class inherits JPanel and implemented paintComponent method but toolwindow doesn't show any graphics unfortunately. What I want to do is draw graphics below the JComboBox.

[image]

Comment: I would post this question at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: Please show your code. Normally this should work.